# How to parse a URL containing some parameters to obtain each parameter as key value pair

Tags: php, string

I have a URL that is of this format:

```
/?basic-property-search=basic-property-search&search_address=306+W+12t+St&search_city=Pawnee&search_state=OK&search_zip=&submit=Submit&price-min=&price-max=&city=&state=&zip=&beds=&baths=&sqft=&status=
```

As you can see sometimes each parameter has a value, sometimes it does not. But all the parameters listed above are always present in the URL. (The key is always there; value may or may not be there as can be seen from above.)

How do I extract all the parameters into an array having key-value pairs with the values being "" (i.e. null string) in case that parameter only has key present in the URL?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php

Comment: All of that is in your $_GET array

Comment: Another method could be using `explode` at least 2 times in a loop. First separating the pairs `variable=value`, then separating the `variable` and the `value`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a work-around from [**php.net**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php#Hcom104527)

```
<?php 
/** 
 * Returns the url query as associative array 
 * 
 * @param    string    query 
 * @return    array    params 
 */ 
function convertUrlQuery($query) { 
    $queryParts = explode('&', $query); 

    $params = array(); 
    foreach ($queryParts as $param) { 
        $item = explode('=', $param); 
        $params[$item[0]] = $item[1]; 
    } 

    return $params; 
} 

$url = "/?basic-property-search=basic-property-search&search_address=306+W+12t+St&search_city=Pawnee&search_state=OK&search_zip=&submit=Submit&price-min=&price-max=&city=&state=&zip=&beds=&baths=&sqft=&status=";

$url = str_replace(array('/?','+'), array('',' '), $url);

print_r(convertUrlQuery($url));

?>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
$x = "/?basic-property-search=basic-property-search&search_address=306+W+12t+St&search_city=Pawnee&search_state=OK&search_zip=&submit=Submit&price-min=&price-max=&city=&state=&zip=&beds=&baths=&sqft=&status=";

parse_str($x, $a);
print_r($a);
```

Output:

```
Array ( 
[/?basic-property-search] => basic-property-search 
[search_address] => 306 W 12t St 
[search_city] => Pawnee 
[search_state] => OK 
[search_zip] => 
[submit] => Submit 
[price-min] => 
[price-max] => 
[city] => 
[state] => 
[zip] => 
[beds] => 
[baths] => 
[sqft] => 
[status] => )
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the $_GET variable:

For example: (Taken From [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_get.asp))

```
> <form action="welcome.php" method="get"> Name: <input type="text"
> name="fname"> Age: <input type="text" name="age"> <input
> type="submit"> </form>
```

Once you submit, you will get the following URL:

**www.example.com/welcome.php?fname=Peter&age=37**

The data can then be accessed as follows

```
Welcome <?php echo $_GET["fname"]; ?>.<br>
You are <?php echo $_GET["age"]; ?> years old!
```

Therefore, it is already set up in an array for you.